# Gradle: include directory as dependency

Tags: java, gradle, directory, dependencies

I have multiple Gradle Java projects in which I am attempting to add the source code of a local project, whose root directory is `/library`, as a dependency that is a directory, just as I can add dependencies that are JARs. I tried using `compile files('/library/src/main/java')`: the packages were imported recursively, but the *.java files were left alone. Can I add `/library/src/main/java` as a dependency to the project? My goal is not having to recompile whenever I make changes to the library.

Comment: First thing, as soon as you make changes to your lib or dependency, gradle or your IDE will have to recompile the source code to get java classes (.class) or the artifact (.jar).

Comment: @KlemensMorbe, then can I include the class files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gradle allows this through [composite builds](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html).
To include the build `/library`, add `includeBuild("/library")` to the `settings.gradle` file of the dependent build. Then declare it as a dependency in `build.gradle` with correct group and name; an explicit version is not unnecessary. As it is now, Gradle will be unable to resolve this dependency, so finally substitute this dependency with the included build by changing `includeBuild("/library")` to

```
includeBuild("/library") {
    dependencySubstitution {
        substitute(module: "<group>:<name>").with(project(":"))
    }
}
```

, which will cause the dependency declared earlier to be replaced by `/library`.

After reloading the Gradle project with your IDE, the classes from `/library` should be available and any changes made to `/library` should be immediately visible to the dependent build.